# RxJS Migration 5 to 6 - Unsubscribe with TakeUntil

Tags: migration, rxjs, subscription, rxjs6

What is the best way to unsubscribe in RxJS 6?

My 'old' RxJS 5 code looks this

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  this.myService.myEventEmitter
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe(this.onDataPolling.bind(this));

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
}
```

On migration to RxJS 6 i run `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate` and got

```js
this.myService.myEventEmitter.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
  .subscribe(this.onDataPolling.bind(this));
```

but this is not working because EventEmitter has no pipe method.

What is the best way to unsubscribe in RxJS 6?

**Edit: This did work after a clean install and is the best way to unsubscribe in RxJS 6.**

Comment: That's not true. `EventEmitter` extends `Subject` that extends `Observable` so it does have `pipe()` method. The problem will be somewhere else.

Comment: you right in my service i'm using import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core". But what is the best way to migrate this???

Comment: But what's the problem with it? `myEventEmitter.pipe(...)` is correct so it doesn't work or it doesn't compile or what?

Comment: it does not compile

Comment: Can you share what error it throws or it's a secret?

Comment: Property "pipe" is not available for type "EventEmitter<{}>"
And got a couple of other migration errors...

Comment: I have a similar problem with `takeUntil`, I'll post details of that tonight.

Comment: @Khalid How did you solve it?

Comment: i think something was wrong with my imported packages. The code is ok and works fine after clean reinstall

Answer (score 10):

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe({YOUR_CODE})
```

This should help.

Answer (score -3):

```
this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
```

To

```
this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: i don't think this is correct. This are two different ways to unsubscribe https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/01/different-ways-unsubscribing-rxjs-observables-angular/